# Macro with function parameter which calls the function

Tags: c, macros

I need a macro which simply calls the function which is passed as parameter to that macro. The function is void type with no parameter.

For example, if I have the following function:

```
void function(void) {
//doSomething
}
```

I need a macro, APPLY_FUNCTION which is called with the **function** parameter and simply calls that function:

```
APPLY_FUNCTION(function);
```

I've tried to define the macro like:

```
#define APPLY_FUNCTION(function)    (function)
```

But it does not work, when I try to call the macro I am getting a "statement with no effect" error.

The question is how should I define that macro?

Comment: What's the point of having this macro? Why not simply call the function?

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Indeed, such a macro would be completely useless. But "Apply" rings a bell, are you trying to implement the [Apply HOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apply)? This won't work with a macro.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define APPLY_FUNCTION(functionname) functionname()

void function(void) {
  printf("Function called\n");
}

int main()
{
  APPLY_FUNCTION(function);
}
```

Output:

```
Function called
```

With your definition:

```
#define APPLY_FUNCTION(function)   (function)
```

The preprocessor generates following line:

```
(function);
```

This is syntaxically correct, but it doesn't call the function, hence the warning.

BTW: you should call the macro rather `CALL_FUNCTION`. You don't *apply* a function, you *call* it.

Answer (score 1):

The quick & dirty version is simply this:

```
#define APPLY_FUNCTION(function) (function)()
```

where the `()` on the end means that this is a function call.

---

I would however prefer to use a type safe C11 version instead:

```
#define APPLY_FUNCTION(function) _Generic((function), void (*)(void): (function)())
```

This prevents the user from passing the wrong kind of function to the macro.